# Php foreach loop execution

Tags: php

I have **$student_object_array** which contains information about **3 students**.
Then I have an array **$room** which contains room_id,capacity and allotment.
 **(Note: There are 2 rooms)**

```
$room[0]->room_id=1;
$room[1]->room_id=2;

$room[0]->capacity=2;
$room[1]->capacity=3;

$room[0]->allotment=0;
$room[1]->allotment=0;
```

Now I have to allot rooms to 3 students... My Code is:-

```
$i=0;


foreach ($student_object_array as $student_object)
{
   $capacity=$room[$i]->capacity;
   $allotment=$room[$i]->allotment;

   $allotment=$allotment_array[$i];
   if($capacity-$allotment!=0)
   {
      allotStudents($student_object->studentId, room[$i]->room_id);
   }
   else
       $i++;
}
```

Now, 
 **at 1st iteration**
  capacity=2 and allotment =0 i.e capacity-allotment != 0 i.e **1st Student Alloted**.

**at 2nd iteration**
  capacity=2 and allotment =1 i.e capacity-allotment != 0 i.e 2nd Student Alloted.

**at 3rd iteration**
  capacity=2 and allotment =2 i.e capacity-allotment == 0 . **It will go in else part and increase the value of i by 1.**

So, loop executes **3 times** as there are **3 students** but only **2 students** alloted here.... Please Help!

Comment: By doing that the 3rd student will also allott in 1st room which has only capacity of 2

Comment: You're resetting $i on every iteration.

Comment: Edited.... Now that initialisation is out of the loop.. but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (updated)

```
 $student_object_array = [
  [
    "name" => "A",
    "room" => ""
  ],
  [
    "name" => "B",
    "room" => ""
  ],
  [
    "name" => "C",
    "room" => ""
  ]
];
$room = [
  [
    "id" => 0,
    "capacity" => 2,
    "allotment" => 0
  ],
  [
    "id" => 1,
    "capacity" => 3,
    "allotment" => 0
  ],
];

$i = 0;

//I use foreach by reference here to be able to modify objects
foreach ($student_object_array as &$student_object)
{
   $canAllot = true;

   //check if current room is full
   while ($room[$i]["capacity"] - $room[$i]["allotment"] == 0)
   {
      //if full procedd to next room until you find free
      $i++;
      if ($i >= count($room)) {
        //no free rooms left
        $canAllot = false;
        break;
      }
   }
   if ($canAllot) {
     allotStudents($student_object, $room, $i);
   } else {
     //no free rooms
     break;
   }
}

var_dump($student_object_array);
echo "<br>";
var_dump($room);

function allotStudents(&$student, &$room, $i) {
  $room[$i]["allotment"]++;
  $student["room"] = $room[$i]["id"];
}
exit();
```

Comment: But i have to put student in 2nd room if 1st room is full.

Comment: And it happens in this code. I believe `allotStudents` somehow knows about current `$i` right? If not, then please edit your question to show, how does this function work.

Comment: Updated. Just checked it, works fine. Student "C" is alloted in 2nd room, as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, when room allotted, maintain its record.

```
$i=0;

foreach ($student_object_array as $student_object)
{
   $capacity=$room[$i]->capacity;
   $allotment=$room[$i]->allotment;

   if($capacity-$allotment!=0)
   {
      $room[$i]->allotment = ++$allotment;
      allotStudents($student_object->studentId, room[$i]->room_id);
   }else{
       $i++;
       $capacity=$room[$i]->capacity;
       $allotment=$room[$i]->allotment;
       $room[$i]->allotment = ++$allotment;
       allotStudents($student_object->studentId, room[$i]->room_id);
   }
}
```

For reference, please see this [Code sample](https://3v4l.org/gDsZv)

Comment: Will not work if next room doesn't exist or is already full on some reason.

Comment: Yes, but OP does not mention these assumptions.  I assumed all rooms are empty and total capacity >= total student . There is always a way for improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
class Room
{
    public $room_id;
    public $capacity;
    public $allotment;  
}

class Student
{
    public $student_id;
    public $name;
}

$one             = new Room;
$one->room_id    = 1;
$one->capacity   = 2;
$one->allotment  = 0;
$two             = new Room;
$two->room_id    = 2;
$two->capacity   = 3;
$two->allotment  = 0;

$foo             = new Student;
$foo->name       = 'foo';
$foo->student_id = 1;
$bar             = new Student;
$bar->name       = 'bar';
$bar->student_id = 2;
$baz             = new Student;
$baz->name       = 'baz';
$baz->student_id = 3;

$rooms           = [$one, $two];
$students        = [$foo, $bar, $baz];

$i = 0;
$associations = [];
foreach($students as $student) {
    $room = $room->allotment == $room->capacity
        ? $rooms[++$i]
        : $rooms[$i];
    $associations[] =
        [
            'student_id' => $student->student_id,
            'room_id'    => $room->room_id
        ];
    $room->allotment++;
}
var_export($associations);
var_export($rooms);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'student_id' => 1,
    'room_id' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'student_id' => 2,
    'room_id' => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'student_id' => 3,
    'room_id' => 2,
  ),
)array (
  0 => 
  Room::__set_state(array(
     'room_id' => 1,
     'capacity' => 2,
     'allotment' => 2,
  )),
  1 => 
  Room::__set_state(array(
     'room_id' => 2,
     'capacity' => 3,
     'allotment' => 1,
  )),
)
```